# Figure out method name from line number in Java?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, bcel

Given a line number, the code file, as well as the compiled class file if necessary, what is the most elegant way to get the signature of the surrounding method (if the line number is even in a method)?

Things to keep in mind:

- the line might not even be in a method
- the line might be in a method of an inner or anonymous class

---

**While Googling I discovered [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026873/method-name-from-line-number) so I'm closing this down myself.**

Comment: There could be more than 1 method on a line.

Comment: in theory yes, Bart, but if so I WANT the solution to crash. :)

Answer (score 1):

That information should be available from the debugger meta information generated by the compiler.

> javac -g:lines foo.java